# Increase mono-fastcgi-server4 performance on nginx

Tags: nginx, mono, fastcgi

I have setup a Nginx server with mono-fastcgi-server4.

It works but when I have simultaneous HTTP request, I get HTTP timeouts error.
My scripts just insert a record into a MySQL table with entity framework and redirect to another server.

I have checked some performance parameter like maxconns and maxreqs (this are fastcgi-mono-server4 parameters). I have set both to 1024 but it does not change anything.

Are there other parameters?